# Box-Plot Analysis

Tags: normal-distribution

I am trying to know if the below box-plot represents a normal distribution or if its similar to a normal but i have some doubts about it.  The median is 2.0, mean is 2.5 and sd is 1.60.  Although the box is symmetric the lengths of whisker are not also mean is not equal to median so i would say this is not similar to a gaussian distribution but i am not 100% sure about.  Also, is safe to say that theres no negative values in the dataset, right? Can anyone please, help me with this analysis?

[image]

Comment: Those are all decent arguments based on this figure alone. Would suggest you post to cross validated (statistics stack exchange)

Comment: As @rubikscube09 said, I think this is more appropriate for stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason why that would be a normal distribution. The boxplot tells you the median, interquartile range, and minimum/maximum values. Unless you had some prior belief that the distribution was normal, you would not believe that it is normal based on this picture.